# There exists an $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k = 2$?

Tags: real-analysis

We consider the map $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x)=x-\frac{1}{4}(x^2-2)$ and, given $x_0 \in \mathbb R$, consider the sequence $(x_k)_{k\ge0}$ satisfying the recurrence: $$x_{k+1}=f(x_k) $$

a) Find the fixed points of $f$, and study their stability.

b) Find $(x_k)_{k\ge0}$ when $x_0=\sqrt 2$.

c) There exists an $x_0 \in \mathbb R-\{\sqrt2\}$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k =\sqrt 2$

d) There exists an $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k = 2$?

So I got that the equilibrium points are $\sqrt2$ and $-\sqrt2$ and that $\sqrt2$ is an attractor and $-\sqrt2$ uis a repeller. At b) I've found that $x_k=\sqrt2,\forall k\in \mathbb N^*$. And I don't know what to do for b) and c). Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: You should ask yourself why you bothered finding the equilibrium points.

Comment: In this general kind of problem draw a graph of $y=f(x)$ and $y=x$ and look at convergence. If it is stair convergence, then prove monotonicity of $x_k$ (i.e. study $f(x)-x$), if it is spiral convergence then prove monotonicity of $x_{2k}$ and $x_{2k+1}$ (i.e. study $f(f(x))-x$). Finally observe $f(x)-\ell$ where $\ell$ is the stable equilibrium.

Comment: If $x_k$ converges then it is a fixed point. How many fixed points did you find? Is $2$ one of them?

Comment: There are only two fixed points. So for both c) and d) the answer would be "no". Am I right?

Comment: For c), what does it mean that $\sqrt{2}$ is an attractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c). Let
$$ f(x)=x-\frac14(x^2-2). $$
It is easy to check that $f(x)\in[\frac12, \frac32]$ for $x\in[\frac12,\frac32]$. Also note that if $x\in[\frac12,\frac32]$,
$$ |x^2-2|\le 2-\frac1{4}=\frac{7}{4} $$
So for $x_0\in[\frac12,\frac32]$, $x_k\in[\frac12,\frac32]$ for all $k\in N$. 
Thus for $x_0\in[\frac12,\frac32]$,
$$ |x_{k+1}-x_k|=\frac14|x_k^2-2|\le\frac{7}{16}<1$$
which implies $\{x_k\}$ converges to $\sqrt 2$.

d). There is no such that $x_0$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=2$. You can use argument by contradiction to check and I omit the detail.